# virtual keyboard covering EditText in Galaxy Tab

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a `EditText` in my app. my problem is that the the virtual keyboard masks my `EditText` while typing. I have tried using different stuffs..

```
 <activity android:name="Myactivity"  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
          android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"></activity>
```

but this problem still exists...do any one have any idea how I can make the `EditText` go up as I type...?

Happy coding...!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just try to do in the Android Manifest file:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize|adjustPan"
```

Also you need to add following code in the activity's OnCreate function:

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

I hope this should work for you.

Comment: I have tried this it just makes the EditText pop a little but still the letters are not visible.

Comment: I think the issues is with my Galaxy Tab OS, the device got accidentally rebooted once and found most of my issues with the Soft Keyboard (both in this app and others) solved. The same app which didn't showed the EditText while typing before was working, perfect now. Wasted my hours on this stupid issue...

Comment: This issue is again occurring in HTC incredible, can this be the case that HTC have custom keyboards and the above solution wont work for that..?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with a Galaxy. Turns out that Android lets you change the behavior of the soft keyboard. You can find the docs here: <s>http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/on-screen-inputs.html</s>

Working Link:
http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html

Basically, there are three input modes:

1) Pan and scan: scrolls the application window to make the focused view visible.

2) Resize: application window is resized to fit the focused view

3) Extract mode: landscape only (look at the picture in the docs... it explains it better than i ever could)

By what i've read, pan and scan (which is set by default) and resize don't work for you... even though the first should scroll the application window and the second should resize it to make the EditText visible. Can you post your layout?

Answer (score 2):

Just add
 android:windowSoftInputMode=”adjustPan” for your activity in manifest file

Comment: if not that..  http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html

Answer (score 1):

Keep the activity settings you posted, in particular:

> android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"

Try wrapping a ScrollView around the layout containing the EditText.  The top of the ScrollView will need to be higher than the top of the SoftKeyboard.  I tested this with many EditTexts in a vertical LinearLayout and found that when the soft keyboard opens, the ScrollView is resized to the visible screen and scrolls as the focus changes to the next EditText.  Also know that ScrollViews within ScrollViews will cause problems.  Hope this helps.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >        
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="192dp" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:inputType="textShortMessage"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext|flagNoEnterAction"

            android:maxLines="1"
            android:maxLength="64"
            />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="192dp" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:inputType="textShortMessage"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext|flagNoEnterAction"

            android:maxLines="1"
            android:maxLength="64"
            />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="192dp" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:inputType="textShortMessage"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext|flagNoEnterAction"

            android:maxLines="1"
            android:maxLength="64"
            />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="192dp" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:inputType="textShortMessage"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext|flagNoEnterAction"

            android:maxLines="1"
            android:maxLength="64"
            />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="192dp" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:inputType="textShortMessage"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext|flagNoEnterAction"

            android:maxLines="1"
            android:maxLength="64"
            />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="192dp" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:inputType="textShortMessage"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext|flagNoEnterAction"

            android:maxLines="1"
            android:maxLength="64"
            />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="192dp" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:inputType="textShortMessage"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext|flagNoEnterAction"

            android:maxLines="1"
            android:maxLength="64"
            />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="192dp" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:inputType="textShortMessage"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext|flagNoEnterAction"

            android:maxLines="1"
            android:maxLength="64"
            />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="192dp" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:inputType="textShortMessage"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext|flagNoEnterAction"

            android:maxLines="1"
            android:maxLength="64"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

EDIT: Clarified ScrollView position.

Answer (score -1):

In the EditText in layout.xml file, add this line

```
android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
```